# Извлечь строки и числовые значения из текстового файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, строки, числа

Имеется текстовый файл:

```
не нужная текстовая строчка
Иванов 
15.1 
10е9/л 
(4.0 - 1 о.о) 

>1 

Петров
11.5 
10е9/л 
(о - 5) 

Сидоров
0.8 
10е9/л 
(о - 2) 

Мельников 
2 
10е9/л 
(1 - 8)
```

Мне необходимо извлечь Фамилии и их числовые значения после пробела. Чтобы на выходе получался вот такой результат:

```
Иванов: 15.1
Петров: 11.5
Сидоров: 0.8
Мельников: 2
```

У меня есть уже шаблон с регулярным выражением, но он извлекает значения, не так как мне нужно.

```
matches_list = re.findall(r'([\w\s]+).+?(\d*\.\d+|\d+)', content, flags=re.DOTALL | re.U)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, мне правильно составить регулярное выражение

Comment: Одно из возможных решений задачи: ```list(map(lambda x: ': '.join(x), re.findall(r'(\S+)(?:\s+)?\n(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', content)))```, где ```content``` - содержимое файла. Но это скорее решение "в лоб". Наверное, лучше использовать ```re.sub```, чтобы раскидать захваченные группы по указанному шаблону "__имя: число__".

Comment: `(\w+)\s*\n([\d\.]+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print('\n'.join(f'{x[0]}: {x[1]}'
                for x in re.findall(r'[\r\n]+([\D]+?)\s*?[\r\n](\d*\.\d+|\d+)',
                content, 
                flags=re.M|re.S)))
```

---

```
Иванов: 15.1
Петров: 11.5
Сидоров: 0.8
Мельников: 2
```

---

**UPDATE:**

```
In [7]: %paste
content="""не нужная текстовая строчка
не нужная текстовая строчка

не нужная текстовая строчка
Иванов
15.1
10е9/л
(4.0 - 1 о.о)

>1

Петров
11.5
10е9/л
(о - 5)

Сидоров
0.8
10е9/л
(о - 2)

Мельников
2
10е9/л
(1 - 8)"""

print('\n'.join(f'{x[0]}: {x[1]}'
                for x in re.findall(r'[\r\n]([^\d\r\n]+?)\s*?[\r\n](\d*\.\d+|\d+)',
                content)))

## -- End pasted text --
Иванов: 15.1
Петров: 11.5
Сидоров: 0.8
Мельников: 2
```

Comment: Вопрос, что значит In [55]:? Питон выдает ошибку с этим значением, а без него все нормально работает

Comment: @Danila00000, это "prompt" интерактивного Python (`ipython`)

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как нужно модифицировать регулярное выражение, чтобы он убирал кучу не нужных мне строк? Например: "не нужная текстовая строчка
не нужная текстовая строчка
не нужная текстовая строчка
Иванов 
15.1 
10е9/л 
(4.0 - 1 о.о) 

>1 

Петров
11.5 
10е9/л 
(о - 5) 

не нужная текстовая строчка
Сидоров
0.8 
10е9/л 
(о - 2) 

Мельников 
2 
10е9/л 
(1 - 8)"      P.S. Регулярные выражения - это моя слабость(

Comment: @Danila00000, добавил исправленный вариант в ответ

Comment: спасибо огромное!!!!)))) Прям очень сильно выручил)